# The partial derivatives of the function $s=\int _u^v\frac{(1-e^t)}{t}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $s=\int _u^v\frac{\left(1-e^t\right)}{t}dt$, I want to find  $\frac{∂s}{∂v}$ and $\frac{∂s}{∂u}$ and their limits as $u$ and $v$ tend to zero.

first i find for

$\frac{∂s}{∂v}=\frac{∂}{∂v}\int _u^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt=\frac{∂}{∂v}\int _u^c\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt+\frac{∂}{∂v}\int _c^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt$

i get

> $\frac{∂s}{∂v}=\frac{1-e^v}{v}$

and then i find for

$\frac{∂s}{∂u}=\frac{∂}{∂u}\int _u^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt=\frac{∂}{∂u}\int _u^c\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt+\frac{∂}{∂u}\int _c^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt$

i get

> $\frac{∂s}{∂u}=\frac{e^u-1}{u}$

and the limits are $\lim _{v\to 0}\frac{1-e^v}{v}=-1$ and $\lim _{u\to 0}\frac{e^u-1}{u}=1$

this is my answer but i don't know if it's correct or is there an error in my calculation?

Comment: Why do you have $x$ as a variable there? As I see it, $s$ is a function of $u$ and $v$ only. By Leibniz' rule, the partial derivatives of $\int_u^v f(t)\,dt$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ are $-f(u)$ and $f(v)$.

Comment: i just edited my answer now i use $\frac{ds}{dt}$, is it correct? @CareBear

Comment: This is still not a reasonable formula. The variable $t$ is not present in the integral $\int_u^v f(t)\,dt$, it was "integrated out". For example, consider the integral $\int_u^v t^2 \,dt $: it is equal to $\frac13 (v^3-u^3)$, with no dependence on $t$.

Comment: should i write the integral in the form of $\int _u^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt=\int _u^c\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt+\int _c^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt$ and then find for $\frac{∂}{∂v}\int _u^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt$ and $\frac{∂}{∂u}\int _u^v\frac{1-e^t}{t}dt$ ? @CareBear

Comment: i just wrote my new answer, if you don't mind please check it for me. thank you so much. :) @CareBear

Comment: Your current answer looks fine.